# Casting string as int causes the value to change

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8.1

I am trying to read in a text file and change the value of a number on a certain line in Powershell in Windows 8.1. The file is somewhat predictable.

I am not currently finding this the best way, but I am trying to track down why this bug occurs. I want to find a number at a certain location and then read the integer value of this.

However, when I do this, I am getting the wrong value.

My code:

```
$data = Get-Content "AssemblyInfo.cs"
Write-Output $data[-2]
Write-Output $data[-2][30]
Write-Output ([int]$data[-2][30])
```

Current output:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]
2
50
```

Expected output:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]
2
2
```

Why is the value changing from 2 to 50 when casting as an int?

Comment: 50 (0x32) is the ASCII value of `'2'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because `$data[-2]` is a `[String]`, and using brackets to get a character in a `[String]` doesn't return a new `[String]`, it returns a `[Char]`.

A `[Char]` is displayed as a single character (like in a string), but is in fact a numeric value. When you cast it to `[int]` you are seeing the character's value, like 64 for `@`.

You could cast to `[String]` first, then to `[int]` to get a numeric version of the single character, or use `[int]::Parse()`:

```powershell
[int][String]$data[-2][30]
# or
[int]::Parse($data[-2][30])
```